# Cloud 9 carousel for Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I want to integrate Cloud9 Carousel in Ionic 2.

Case-1: I import file like this.

```
import { Cloud9Carousel } from '../../assets/js/jquery.cloud9carousel.js';
```

Doesn't work

Case-2: I import like this.

```
import * as Cloud9Carousel from '../../assets/js/jquery.cloud9carousel.js';
```

Doesn't work too.

My .ts is written as

```
ngOnInit(){


   $(function() {
      var showcase = $("#showcase")

      showcase.Cloud9Carousel( {
        yPos: 42,
        yRadius: 48,
        mirrorOptions: {
          gap: 12,
          height: 0.2
        },
        buttonLeft: $(".nav > .left"),
        buttonRight: $(".nav > .right"),
        bringToFront: true,
        onLoaded: function() {
          showcase.css( 'visibility', 'visible' )
          showcase.css( 'display', 'none' )
          showcase.fadeIn( 1500 )
        }
      } );


    })
    }
```

## HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="showcase" class="noselect">
      <img class="cloud9-item" src="assets/menu/firefox.png" alt="Firefox"> 
      <img class="cloud9-item" src="assets/menu/wyzo.png" alt="Wyzo">
      <img class="cloud9-item" src="assets/menu/opera.png" alt="Opera"> 
      <img class="cloud9-item" src="assets/menu/chrome.png" alt="Chrome"> 
      <img class="cloud9-item" src="assets/menu/iexplore.png" alt="Internet Explorer"> 
      <img class="cloud9-item" src="assets/menu/safari.png" alt="Safari"> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Error:
showcase.Cloud9Carousel is not a function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try 'declare var Cloud9Carousel:any' after the imports.Don't forget to include the js file in index.html

Comment: @Naveen Thanks for reply. I followed the steps. but didn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

Put in `ngAfterViewInit()`, because this function is launched after content is presented, then the DOM is ready to be modified.